# jquery get values from deferred objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have some `<span>`s in several tables.

```
<table class="table-transactions">
    <tr>
        <td id="table1">
            <span class="test"></span> blah blah blah
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-transactions">
    <tr>
        <td id="table2">
            <span class="test"></span> blah blah blah
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-transactions">
    <tr>
        <td id="table3">
            <span class="test"></span> blah blah blah
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-transactions">
    <tr>
        <td id="table4">
            <span class="test"></span> blah blah blah
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For each of those tables, I check to see if it exists (may not as that are created dynamically using php), I use a separate ajax call to update the `<span>` text as they are calling different urls.

```
if($('#table1').length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/script/1',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'data': 'something', 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#table1 .test').text(response);
        }
    });
}

if($('#table2').length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/script/2',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'data': 'something', 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#table2 .test').text(response);
        }
    });
}

if($('#table3').length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/script/3',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'data': 'something', 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#table3 .test').text(response);
        }
    });
}

if($('#table4').length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/script/4',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'data': 'something', 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#table4 .test').text(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Some of these urls return data faster than others and when all of the `<span>`s are populated, I want to run a function.

I thought about using deferred objects but I can't get it to work.  It runs fine but I'm unsure how to:

- How to return the text value to the deferred object
- Using the promises, I don't know how to do something with them

This is what I came up with

```
var promises = [];
var all = function(array) {
    $('.table-transactions').each(function(elm) {
        promises.push(function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
                dfd.resolve($(elm).find('.test').text());
            }).promise();
        });
    });
};

$.when(all(promises)).then(function(results) {

    console.log(results);
    //alert('hello');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Here is an example of my ajax calls
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/script',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'data': 'something', 
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('.test').text(response);
    }
});
```

In the success function, I would target that specific table span. These are just simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything. It should return the promise array

Also `$.when` wasn't designed to accept array of promises (unfortunately) but you can use `$.when.apply()`

Alternatively in modern browsers you can use `Promise.all()`

```
var all = function(array) {
    var promises = [];
    $('.table-transactions').each(function(elm) {
        promises.push(function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
                dfd.resolve($(elm).find('.test').text());
            }).promise();
        });
    });
    // return the array
    return promises
};

$.when.apply($, all()).then(function() {    
    console.log(arguments);        
});

// OR
Promise.all( all()).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: How do I get the value of the span? Currently it returns Arguments(3) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
0
:
ƒ ()
1
:
ƒ ()
2
:
ƒ ()
callee
:
ƒ ()
length
:
3
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
:
ƒ values()
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: I forgot to unwrap your anonymous function. Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/bzmbuL1y/ Would be better if you showed what you are doing with the ajax since `$.ajax` returns a promise also and doesn't require  a new $.Deferred

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, I've updated question to show ajax call